# Show rendered HTML inside ACE Editor

Tags: javascript, angular, ace-editor

I am using ace editor with [ng2-ace-editor](https://github.com/fxmontigny/ng2-ace-editor#readme) in angular 7. I am trying to make an editor for some specific syntax. I want to recognize certain pattern before add content dynamically inside the Editor and replace with some kind of HTML. I want to display that HTML as rendered part, not as code. Currently when I add the content inside the ace is rendered as code.

[image]

I want to show as:

[image]

I am using @ViewChild to get the editor on my component

```
export class ViewAceEditorComponent  {
  @ViewChild('editor') aceComponent: AceEditorComponent;
```

Then, I use setTxt() method to assign the code to the editor dynamically.

```
this.aceComponent.setText(this.myTextWithHtmlCode);
```

Any ideas on how to render the HTML instead of the code?

Comment: Why would you want Ace to render the HTML formatted code? Ace's purpose is to serve as an editor to write i. e. HTML code, but not to render it inside of the editor.

Comment: @SparkFountain because in fact I am using as code editor but for Lucene syntax. but there are specific syntax that I want to show more readable as html elements instead code. something like `416e1c02-04bc-47ab-909d-ae8813c539d7:fec6b22e5af9-4de6-9f69-25f1e8992467` as `Name2:Name2` but only in the render not in the text property.

Comment: I don't think that this is possible. The code (= text) which is displayed by Ace cannot be "modified" in a way that some other styled code would be rendered in the editor. You can define some syntax highlighting or even error detection rules like in `javascript` mode, but rendering the given code text in a certain way is not intended.